# Laravel Exception is taking user to login page

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am building an App with Laravel and Vuejs. I am validating my Data with with Laravel Validator. Then I am giving back to the `axios` request. Please take a look in the code.

Axios to Sent Data:

```
saveCustomerInDB(customer) {
  axios.post('/api/data/user/storeCustomer', 
  {
    customer_name: customer.customer_name
  }).then( (response) => {
     console.log(response);
  }).catch( (error) => {
      console.log("Error", error);
  });
},
```

Then the validation of Laravel Controller:

```
try {
  $this->validate($request, [
      'customer_name' => 'required'
  ]);
    
   return response()->json([
      'status' => 'success',
      'msg'    => 'Okay',
   ], 200);
}
catch(ValidationException $exception) {
   return response()->json([
      'status' => 'error',
      'msg'    => 'Error',
       'errors' => $exception->errors(),
   ], 422);
}
```

After giving the exception it is going to Login Page!!

If I changed it to this `return response()->json($exception->errors());` then it is giving me success message but in data errors are coming!! Very strange!!

What can I do now?

Comment: What is the network code on the successful request??

Comment: {data: {…}, status: 201, statusText: "Created", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

Comment: that is wrong since your code does not include any 201 codes. i need to see more code

Comment: Oh Sorry. I have changed the 201 to 200. But it's okay.

Comment: but then your validation is not triggering? has nothing to do with how you handle validation errors

Comment: Validation is working but its going to Login page.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/591438?key=972e6860dfad52b5c4e075da013b8f64

Comment: the something is wrong in your setup the route you are calling are it under api.php routes?

Comment: Yes. From api.php

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the try statement, you'll see that the problem is you're either not passing in the expected Illuminate\Http\Request instance to $this->validate(), which is done like so: `$this->validate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, [ ... ])`, or there's a validation rule that did not pass. Please remove the try statement momentarily and tell me what the real exception is.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem appears after adding the exception, you probably need to recheck if you have imported the validation exception on the top of the file.

`use Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException`

or alternatively you could do

`catch(\ValidationException $exception)`.

Comment: I have added this.